# How to merge two point cloud with there scales are different?

Tags: computer-vision, point-cloud-library, slam, structure-from-motion

We now are using SFM to reconstruct our school building.
But our school is too big to reconstruct them by once.
So we decide to divide them into several blocks and reconstruct them, and merge these point clouds.

Because of the scale ambiguity of SFM, so the point clouds' scale is different.

And point cloud merge algorithm, such as ICP, can only estimate rotation and translation transform matrix, but not similarity transform matrix.

So,  are there exist an algorithm to merge two point cloud with different scale or any paper?

Comment: How many parts do you have ? If it is a one-shot project and you just want the result you could open the clouds in CloudCompare (for instance) and measure reference objects to find the scale yourself.